# What to enter to connect to localhost windows with external terminal?

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, terminal

I just downloaded a terminal client (ZOC Termial) and I want it to connect to the localhost from windows that I am currently on. So I want it to act like Command Prompt from windows. But I don't know what to enter as a Host, Port Connection type, User and password.

[image]

Comment: Your going to have to provide us with more information because we don't know what to enter either, you have not given us any information we could use, to answer your question.  I assume you have tried localhost?  If you don't know what your username and password and the port your using we can't possibly know that.  You don't normally use Zoc Terminal as a command prompt replacement....

Comment: First I am on windows 10. I have some connection types that I can select. Named Pipe, Rlogin, SecureShell, serial/modem, telnet, telnet ssl, and windows modem. Not sure what more information i can give. Most terminal software connect to localhost automatically but not this one.

Comment: Your configuration as in the screenshot would be your SSH username and password on the port you configured SSH to run on

Comment: I am not trying to connect to a server with ssh I know how to do that. I want it to connect to the localhost from the windows OS. For example I want to be able to browse inside the C:// and run stuff there. Just like I am on CMD.

Comment: Again; The client your using isn't a command prompt replacement...

Comment: So what you are saying is ZOC is impossible to connect to localhost and act like command prompt?

Comment: I man saying exactly that based on its advertised feature set.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to enable Telnet in Windows (it's not enabled by default).

In the "Programs and Features" Control Panel, click “Turn Windows features on or off”, find the "Telnet Client" and check it. You may have to reboot.

Then perhaps use localhost or the 127.0.0.1 IP address. Telnet uses port 23.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and rebooted windows. However I am getting this error: [TELNET] FAIL: ::1 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: port 992 is secure telnet. Try the "telnet SSL" connection?

Comment: I get the same error. There are some advanced configurations for telnet however. Have you tried it? https://www.emtec.com/zoc/

Comment: You'd also need a password setup for your username and you may need to specify computername\username as the username... just some stuff to try! Good luck